# How to use ghcr.io image for GitHub workflows

Tags: docker, github, continuous-integration, workflow

[This is my current Workflow file](https://github.com/NarutoXY/pacstall/blob/develop/.github/workflows/remote-bash.yml)

I want to use my custom docker image for testing, but CI fails for some reason. The image is public. The current implementation is borrowed from a Stack Overflow Answer.

## Workflow File

```
name: test install script
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-20.04]
        container:
            image: ghcr.io/pacstall/pacstall:latest
            credentials:
               username: narutoxy
               password: ${{  secrets.DOCKER_CONTAINER_REGISTRY_TOKEN  }}
    steps:
      - name: remote-bash
        uses: shinhwagk/remote-bash@0.0.1
        with:
          args:
        env:
          REMOTE_BASH_URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NarutoXY/pacstall/develop/.github/workflows/pacstall_check.sh
```

## Content of remote bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
function banner() {
  MESSAGE="${1}"
  echo "====================================
  $MESSAGE
  ===================================="
}

banner "Installing neofetch"
pacstall -P -I neofetch
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Something went wrong"
    exit 1
fi
banner "Installing deb package"
pacstall -P -I brave-browser-beta
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Something went wrong"
    exit 1
fi
banner "Testing removal"
pacstall -P -R neofetch
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Something went wrong"
    exit 1
fi
pacstall -P -R brave-browser-beta
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Something went wrong"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Please make sure your question can be followed even if the link goes bad.

Comment: I double checked and the link is up. I'm new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: "If" the link goes bad. Your develop branch will change over time, or could be deleted, so anyone visiting this question months or years later will have no idea what you are asking. Instead, provide enough context directly in the text of the question, including configuration files, code, commands run, and their output. Use the link for supporting material.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm gonna add everything in post.